# joomla 2.5 ajax api

Tags: ajax, joomla2.5

I would like to setup some little ajax support for my joomla page, in detail: I would like to send logging messages from the frontend to the backend via ajax and store them in database.

In drupal this can be done by adding a path and a callback inside a module, so how can this be achieved in joomla 2.5, so that there is an url like:

`http://www.domain.com/log` which leads to a function call?

Greetings..

Comment: Did you try this- http://docs.joomla.org/Ajax_using_MooTools

Comment: that leads to a component... isn't there something with less afford?

Comment: @philipp I've done this by creating a an ajax helper file that works standalone, but if you want the best solution, you better create a component for it

Comment: that is just what would like to avoid, but seems to be no other way... on the other hand, it is more easy to create an view for the logs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way would be to create a component to handle the call, but as you write most of the time it seems a bit overkill for just a module. 
Another way would be to create a standalone php-file that uses the Joomla-library. This file could then easily be called from wherever you like. It's like a mini-version of Joomla with the advantage of having all libraries available:

```
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
if (!defined('JPATH_BASE')){
    define('JPATH_BASE', '..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..');
}
define('JPATH_LIBRARIES', JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries');
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . DS . 'import.php';
$var = JRequest::getVar('my_var');
```

To access the DB-object, you would need to manually set the options to the DB-object since this file won't access the configuration files (you can program this of course).

```
$option = array(); //prevent problems  
$option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name 
$option['host']     = 'db.myhost.com';    // Database host name 
$option['user']     = 'myuser';       // User for database authentication 
$option['password'] = 'mypass';   // Password for database authentication 
$option['database'] = 'bigdatabase';      // Database name 
$option['prefix']   = 'abc_';             // Database prefix (may be empty)  
$db = & JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
```